# How to display a notification over a running activity?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am building a wear+mobile app using Android Wear sdk.
When the user speeches a text, it is passed to the mobile app that makes a db query and returns the result to the wear app.
If i use messages it runs fine, but i would like the mobile app to create a notification for the wear app.
If i create a notification it is correctly sent but it is shown under the running wear app ... how can i send a notification that is displayed OVER the running activity?

Comment: What is the purpose of that notification? Do user need to interact with this "notification" being on top of another app? Can you write some example of usage?